# How to automatically create directory structure in Linux?

Tags: linux, directory, structure

I have a problem, I have a catalog `/home/robert` in which there are subdirectories: `Dog`, `Cat`, `Bird`, `Horse`

I want to create a `Test` and `Test1` (automatically) in each of these directories to get:

```
/home/robert/Dog/Test
/home/robert/Dog/Test1

/home/robert/Cat/Test
/home/robert/Cat/Test1

/home/robert/Bird/Test
/home/robert/Bird/Test1

/home/robert/Horse/Test
/home/robert/Horse/Test1
```

Is this possible to do, for example, one command with regular expressions, or even better in a text file, I enter:

```
Test
Test1
```

And somehow I take the name "Test" and "Test1" and I'm going to the command that will create such a structure of catalogs?

I tried:

- `mkdir /home/robert/*/Test`
- `mkdir /home/robert/{*}/Test`
- `mkdir /home/robert/[*]/Test`

Unfortunately, this does not work

Comment: You could try something like `find /home/robert/* -type d -maxdepth 0 -print0 | xargs -0 -iDIR mkdir -p DIR/Test DIR/Test1`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you ! What you wrote above let me look more precisely on the internet. Thanks to this I wrote a script that solves my problem completely. (The above catalogs "Cat, Dog etc. I only gave as an example), I really wanted to achieve the following solution:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    mkdir -- {1..300}
      for dir in*; do
      mkdir -- "$dir"/{documents,desktop,email};
    done
```

Before performing the script I had:

```
$ tree my_office_users/
my_office_users/
└── script
```

And after run script, I have 1 to 300 folders and in each of them catalogs: desktop and documents and email.

And that was it!

```
$ tree my_office_users
my_office_users/
├── 1
│   ├── desktop
│   ├── documents
│   └── email
├── 10
│   ├── desktop
│   ├── documents
│   └── email
├── 100
│   ├── desktop
│   ├── documents
│   └── email
├── 101
│   ├── desktop
│   ├── documents
│   └── email
 .
 .
 .
├── 99
│   ├── desktop
│   ├── documents
│   └── email
└── script
```

Answer (score 0):

This meets your criteria but I'm not sure it's what you wanted.

```
for dir in deleteme/*/;do mkdir -- "$dir"/{Test,Test1}; done
```

where `deleteme` in your case would be `/home/robert`

If it has to be only a `mkdir` command you can do this but it doesn't scale:

```
mkdir -p deleteme/{Dog/{Test1,Test2},Cat/{Test1,Test2},Bird/{Test1,Test2},Horse/{Test1,Test2}}
```